# How many API calls does a typical web app make on load?

Tags: design-patterns, web-applications, api-design

I'm working on a relatively simple web app that uses its own API to pull data on page load. Nothing fancy. I've run into a few cases where it'd be simpler to run two GET requests while loading a page's content, but I'm having trouble finding any information about how common multiple API calls are, and best practices around them.

How many API calls does a typical web app make to its own APIs when doing something as simple as a page load? What's the best approach once a RESTful API is already in place?

Comment: Three. Ask Mr. Owl. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UYvsk6_foc

Answer (score 2):

How many API calls a web application has really depends on how complex the web application will be.

What I suggest is that to define the performance goal of your web application, like average loading time of your web page, or 90 percentile response time, etc.

Once you have your goals defined, you can check if the web application developed satisfy the goals. If not, there are multiple ways to tune the application.

e.g. combine multiple calls into one Restful call is one way. Try to minimize the page content by enabling server sider HTTP compression, JS/CSS compression, etc. will be helpful.